# modify the sql result to json in python

Tags: python, json

I know this might be a level 0 question, but I'm stuck here

I'm using SQL Alchemy to get the sql result.

```
with db.connect() as conn:
    data = conn.execute('''select * from tables''')
    json_data = json.dumps([(dict(row.items())) for row in data])
    conn.close()
    return json_data
```

The result for the above snippet is

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Ashton", "age": 20, "nationality": "US"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Kevin", "age": 20, "nationality": "US"}]
```

But how do I get the response with a name?

```
{"citizens":[{"id": 1, "name": "Ashton", "age": 20, "nationality": "US"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Kevin", "age": 20, "nationality": "US"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following...

```
with db.connect() as conn:
    data = conn.execute('''select * from tables''')
    json_data = json.dumps({"citizens": [(dict(row.items())) for row in res]})
    return json_data
```

Note: you also don't need call `conn.close()`. This is called by default at the end of the `with db.connect()` context manager.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#basic-usage